# calculating the distance traveled in android(while moving)

Tags: android

hai i need to calculate the distance using GPS in android while the bike is moving.while i'm giving the latitude and longitude values in the emulator for aprx its giving the correct value, but by using the packet data of the device and running the app,the values are changing with out any movement. This is the code, please suggest.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        showCurrentLocation();
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                clearButton();
            }
    });     
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        // Getting LocationManager object
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Creating an empty criteria object
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);
            clat = location.getLatitude();
            clon = location.getLongitude();
            a[0] = clat;
            a[1] = clon;

            if (location != null)
                onLocationChanged(location);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Creating an empty criteria object
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
            // Get the location from the given provider
            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);
            plat = location.getLatitude();
            plon = location.getLongitude();
            a[2] = plat;
            a[3] = plon;
            if(a[0]!=a[2]||a[1]!=a[3])
        {
                dis += getDistance(a);
        }

            a[0] = plat;
            a[1] = plon;
            Log.e("aa", String.valueOf(dis));
            TextView tvDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tvDistance.setText(String.valueOf(dis) + " km");
        }
    }
   public double getDistance(double a[]) {
    double earthRadius = 6371; //kilometers
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(a[2] -a[0] );
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(a[3] -a[1]);
    double b = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a[0])) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(a[2])) *
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(b), Math.sqrt(1-b));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist;
    }

    protected void clearButton(){
        dis=0;
        showCurrentLocation();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, You are using getLastKnownLocation(). Some time it will give invalid/wrong location pairs, because it will take from last updated place.. and the better way is to use googleplayservices lib. it will help you get the moving speed and your accurate location. you can find the distance between current and designation location using google distance api

Comment: googleplayservices lib prevent from deploying to Nokia, Amazon, and others not google android devices. I wonder if the bug you speak of is wanted by g.

Comment: @akhila I am facing the same issue.Did you get the solution?..

Answer (score 0):

You could do a step and call getDistance not when the position is different, but when the elapsed time is relevant for a bike speed (1s ?).

```
private long timestamp = 0;

public double getDistance(double a[]) {
    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    (....)
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     (...)
     if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp > 1000){
          dis += getDistance(a);
     }
```